# mvc 6 ef7 Customer table object is null in AppDbContext - there is data in the database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, object, null, dbcontext

When I enter URL localhost:xxx/api/Customers, it showed "is null".  I looked at the variable in debugger mode, it show the table customers object is null;

[image: debug image]

Remember there is data in the table. Any idea?

Customer class

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string lName { get; set; }
}
```

appsettings.json

```
{
"Data": {
"DefaultConnection": {
  "ConnectionString": "Server=.\\sqlexpress;Database=EF7;Trusted_Connection=True;"
}
}
```

AppDbContext

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers;
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder Builder)
    {
        Builder.Entity<Customer>().HasKey(c => c.Id);
        base.OnModelCreating(Builder);
    }
 }
```

CustomersController

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class CustomersController : Controller
{
    AppDbContext _ctx { get; set; }
    public CustomersController([FromServices] AppDbContext ctx)
    {
        _ctx = ctx;
    }
    // GET: api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Get()
    {
        if(_ctx.Customers!=null)
            return Json(_ctx.Customers.ToList());
        else {
            return Json("is null");
        }
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    IConfigurationRoot Configuration;
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var Builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = Builder.Build();
    }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddEntityFramework().AddSqlServer().AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(o=>o.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseIISPlatformHandler();
        app.UseMvc();
    }

    // Entry point for the application.
    public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, my Dbset is a field instead of property. So I just changed to DbSet Customer {get;set}